# How can we broadcast live video from SWF running in flash player to Azure Media Services Live Streaming?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, azure, video, live

As I understood we can broadcast encoded video streams directly from swf. Also we can connect to RTMP servers.Are there any tutorials/instructions on how to broadcast video streams from flash clients to windows Azure Media Services Live Streaming Units?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try by using http://www.telestream.net/wirecast/overview.htm. Wirecast 6 has configuration integration with Azure Media Services. We accept RTMP ingest or Smooth Streaming ingest. After setting up the stream, you can look for ingest URL in the portal.

For more information, please look into this blog post: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/10/getting-started-with-live-streaming-using-the-azure-management-portal/